# How to stop 2 digit numbers going to 00?

Tags: python-3.x

Making a cookie clicker I encountered some problems including the title. Here is my code:

```
#imports

from getkey import getkey

#variables/strings/int whatever they're called

money = 0

cookies = 0

#loop

while True:

    print(f"{cookies}\n${money}\n\n[1]offer1: {offer1}")

    click = getkey()

    if click == "\n":

        cookies += 1

    if click == "1":

        for cookies in range(cookies):

            money += offer1
```

If cookies are sold to offer1 and it has 2 or more digits, it will show 2 numbers that may or may not be 00 or 0 (random num)

Does anyone have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Also copy and paste the code into a python compiler, preferably replit because I use that sorry I forgot :b

Comment: Do you have an initial value for `offer1`? you might be missing something like `offer1 = 1`

Comment: I do. I could show the whole code but it's 180 lines :D

Comment: try: click = int(click) except: pass
if click contains string of number it will be converted to number and perform operation related to number like click >= 1 and so with string like "\n"